# Position of CGRect doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, position, cgrect

I try to put position on my node with `CGPointMake` and whatever I right `CGRectGetMin/Mid/Max` values node doesn't show up and using `NSLog` always output 0 for Example:

```
- (id)initOnLeftSide
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.name = @"leftPlayer";
    Paddle *leftPaddle = [[Paddle alloc] initWithName:@"leftPaddle"];
    leftPaddle.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x + 50, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:leftPaddle];

}
return self;
}
```

Height shows up as 0, even when I use `self.parent.frame.size.height` still outputs 0. only way that paddle will work is `self.frame.origin.y` but I want to create paddle universal, so it will show up on iphone and same place on ipad. **What did  I do wrong and how can I fix that?**

Comment: you have a lot more issues going on then you are showing,  if your height is zero thern there is something wrong with `self`, whatever `self` is

Comment: Try setting the frame first than give position and also is leftpaddle is a custom view than you are not loading its nib properly

Answer (score 0):

Because CGRectGetMidY takes min value which equal 0. Try add number:

```
CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 20;
```

If you want height try CGRectGetHeight(self.frame);